# How to call REST service method with RestTemplate

Tags: spring, rest, resttemplate

Can any please tell me how can I call following service method with RestTemplate. Thanks.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/file/upload", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
 public String fileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) { }
```

Comment: Have you looked into resttemplate? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-resttemplate http://docs.spring.io/spring-android/docs.old/1.0.x/reference/html/rest-template.html

Answer (score 0):

```
  RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
 ResponseEntity<youclass> response= rest.exhange(url(your url to post or get), data(data u r sending to server), yourclass.class);
response.getBody() //response back from the server
```